# Iframe issue. I have one pdf to show in my page on that pdf also show an text by use of CSS its not working in ie

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/K4uEs/2/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height:600px;width:1000px;position:relative;margin:auto;">
            <div style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:50px;height:100px;z-index:9999;background:red;">This is not visible </div>
             <iframe src="http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf" height="50%" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what's actually the question?

Comment: Samuele Mattiuzzo position:absolute not working on iframe. This the issue

Comment: He's having problems getting the little red div to show over the iframe. He edited his question badly.

Comment: where is your question? what exactly is the problem? what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Your iframe has no absolute positioning. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: @sumit - please don't ask the same question again. We don't allow that sort of thing on Stack Overflow. Please see: [FAQ#bounty]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assiming, by the z-index on your inner div and that you're trying to position it over the iframe.

It doesn't work, because Frames (including IFrames) are independent subwindows over the original window, so it doesn't matter how much you increment you z-index, the div will only be higher in the index of objects in the base windows, and will never get on top of the object in the subwindow.

In you specific case it would be even more complex to do, as the subwindow is draw by a different program (I'm assuming Acrobat Reader, but it would depend on you computer configuration).

Another element over which you usually can't position anything is OBJECT and EMBED - think of flash, for instance, because that space is draw by a different program. It may work on some browsers, but it's not specified to work and it doesn't work in most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It works in Firefox, so I don't know.

Have you tried giving the iframe a z-index lower than the previous div?

Answer (score 1):

Because you don;t have `position:absolute` on the iframe, you have it on the div before it;

try this:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:50px;height:100px;z-index:9999;background:red;">This is not visible 
         <iframe src="http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf" height="50%" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is awful, but the accepted answer is wrong...so for the benefit of anyone else that stumbles upon this...

Yes you can overlay a layer on top of an iframe.

Reasons you might want to do this: You can do this to blend a rectangular embed into a circle shape or capture click events (ie via a transparent layer).

It is simply a matter of positioning another element over the iframe element.  There is nothing special about the iframe element that prevents this.

However this is different that accessing content or events WITHIN the iframe itself.  This may be restricted especially if the origin of the iframe window is different than the origin of the containing window and there are a variety of settings that can impact this.

But anyway, yes overlaying an iframe is no big thing.  Here is the obligatory demo.

https://codepen.io/matp/pen/WNaVOmq

```js
var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay'),
    textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');

overlay.addEventListener('click', function () {
    textArea.textContent = textArea.textContent + '\n' + 'Overlay received click.';
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container iframe {
  width: 560px;
  height: 315px;
}
.container .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5);
}

textarea {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/e09xig209cQ"></iframe>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div><textarea></textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For others landing here the 2011 original Problem has been resolved by Modern Browsers and use of modern HTML4/5 so eventually as desired by the original poster modern browsers will behave, correctly and place the red box above the PDF in an iFrame. As per first Answer in 2011 FireFox could be expected to work but other browsers like **Internet Explorer AS PER QUESTION** may not have. For your own tests I suggest replace the linked file with https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf as it currently has no CORS issues.

**Here it works in IE replacement Modern Edge III+**

[image]

Every browser can be different absolute positions so here in Chrome it would cover a sidebar and title.

[image]

Even if the PDF is not visible due to CORS the overlay should still function as its "bound" to the framework. (In a true PDF viewer its generally not possible to bind to the PDF page contents, unless an annotation editor does that for you.)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

PDF **Only works** if the client **has the plugin** to open it **at the browser**!
Examples: Acrobat Reader, Chrome internal PDF Reader, etc.

**Tip/Answer:**
Convert your **PDF** Files into **JPG** Files and use a **PageFlip** Flash to read them.

**Example:** http://www.revistainpeople.com/edicoes

*Tip 2:*
You can easly convert pdf's on linux using this command: `convert sample.pdf sample.png`

**EDIT:**
If you use pageflip (flash) you don't have problems with z-index property, it will work normaly, because you will find always adobe flash player on clients instead some nasty plugin to read pdf's.

Comment: You can't, as i've said, they use different plugins, different ways of processing, some of them could respect z-index, others not.